# RecallNumber in Aleph mode declarations

Tags: prolog, logic, aleph

[Here](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/activities/programinduction/Aleph/aleph.html#SEC8) is the definition of RecallNumber in the Aleph Manual. As I understand it so far RecallNumber defines an upper bound (Either a number or * for unbounded) for "the number of successfull calls" of a given predicate. But I'm lost on the context of the "successfull calls". Is this at some point during the search for a clause? Or does it bound the number of times the predicate can appear in the body of the learned clause? Something else?

I would appreciate any explanation or links to explanations.